# Как передать значение переменных js в python(eel)?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, eel

Есть js функция которая обрабатывает input и записывает значения в переменные.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Speed Parser</title>
        <script src="eel.js"></script>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="instaParser.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@1,100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
    <input id="login" type="text" placeholder="Ваш логин" required="">
    <br>
    <input id="passw" type="password" placeholder="Ваш пароль" required="">
    <hr>
    <div id="form_radio_block">
    <div class="form_radio_group">
        <div class="form_radio_group-item">
            <input id="radio-1" type="radio" name="radio" value="rFollowers" checked>
            <label for="radio-1">Подписчики</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form_radio_group-item">
            <input id="radio-2" type="radio" name="radio" value="rFollowing">
            <label for="radio-2">Подписки</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form_radio_group-item">
            <input id="radio-3" type="radio" name="radio" value="rLike">
            <label for="radio-3">Пост+like</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <input id="urlPage" type="text" placeholder="URL профиля" required="">
    <hr>
    <button id="projectStart">START</button>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function startParser_js() {
            eel.iPfollowers();
        }
        eel.expose(logIn_js);
        function logIn_js(){
            loginJS = document.getElementById('login').value;
            passwJS = document.getElementById('passw').value;
    
        }
        jQuery('#projectStart').on('click', function() {
            logIn_js();
            startParser_js();
        })
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Как передать значение переменных `loginJS` и `passwJS` в python.

Для связки использую eel.

```
import time
import random
from selenium import webdriver
import eel
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

@eel.expose
def iPfollowers():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\Евгений\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe')
    login = "ЗДЕСЬ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ JS ПЕРЕМЕННОЙ loginJS"
    passw = "ЗДЕСЬ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ JS ПЕРЕМЕННОЙ passwJS"
    urlInsta = "https://www.instagram.com/"
    driver.get(urlInsta)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В python:

```
iPfollowers(loginjs,passwjs):
   login = loginjs
   passw = passwjs
...
```

В JS:

```
eel.iPfollowers(loginjs,passwjs);
```